# How to retrieve some data from API and use it in all the pages of a NexJS application before rendering on client side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-context

I have a NextJS application where I have a home page (`index.js`) and two other pages About(`about.js`) & Contact Us(`contact.js`).

I have created a BaseLayour.js file with is wrapping NextJS's `MyApp` component in `_app.js` file.

```
import React from "react";

import BaseLayout from "../layouts/BaseLayout";

function MyApp(props) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props;

  return (
    <BaseLayout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </BaseLayout>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

This `BaseLayout` component looks like this -

```
import React from "react";

import SEO from "../components/SEO";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";

function BaseLayout(props) {
  const { children } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <SEO />
      <Header />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default BaseLayout;
```

As you can see above in the BaseLayout file, there is an SEO component (React). It contains some common metadata for all the pages. I have an API(`api/getmetadata/`) that delivers all the metadata in JSON format.

This metadata is supposed to load on the server-side so that the page will be optimized for SEO.

How can we call the API in order to retrieve the data on each request but only on the server-side?

What I have tried till now -

1. Tried calling API in the SEO component itself, but it is not running on the server-side as it is just a React component.
2. Tried creating a React context, and called the API from SEO/BaseLayout components, the API call is still not being made from the server-side.
3. Tried using `getServerSideProps` in the `index.js` page to call the API and retrieve the data, which worked perfectly, but the problem is we need to share the data between all the pages, not just the `index.js` home page.

Any help will be appreciated, If we can somehow make the API call and retrieve the data in the SEO component, it will solve our problem.

Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: I think that you could solve it by combining the 2 and 3 approaches. 1. Define a global `AppContext` using the Context API and provide it to the whole app (This context will contain a state which includes the data loaded from the API). 2. Load the data in the `index.js` file with `getServerSideProps` and store them in the Context state created. 3. Load the data from the context in any page or component using the `useContext` hook

Comment: I agree with Luca, but FYI you can also use `getInitialProps`  (instead that `getServerSideProps` ) inside `_app.js` (you cant do the same with `getServerSideProps`) and this allows you to fetch serverside data for all the pages.